# spree_globalize was resolved to 3.1.0.beta when spree version is '~>3.3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Is it possible to have model translation for Spree 3.3 (through `spree_globalize`) in Rails 5.1.3?

I followed the instructions but when I run `bundle update`, I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_i18n":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    spree_i18n (= 3.3.0.rc1)

  In Gemfile:
    spree_i18n

    spree_globalize was resolved to 3.1.0.beta, which depends on
      spree_i18n (~> 3.1.0.beta)
```

And my Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'spree', '~> 3.3.0.rc1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'

gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n'
gem 'spree_globalize', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_globalize', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: Can you include your `Gemfile` in the question too?

Comment: Yes i include my Gemfile

Comment: I can't see your Gemfile. Can you add the contents of your Gemfile to the StackOverflow question?